# Visual c# with vs2010 erro : cannot deduce auto type initializer required error in my code which is working on vs2012

Tags: java, android

cannot deduce auto type initializer required error in my code which is working on vs2012

```
RefreshAndroidSomeList()
{
   setContentView(R.layout.directory_picker);
    setTitle(dir.getAbsolutePath());
    Button btnChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChoose);
    String name = dir.getName();
    if(name.length() == 0)
        name = "/";
    btnChoose.setText("Choose " + "'" + name + "'");
    btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            returnDir(dir.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: corrected it sorry that was a typo

Comment: I don't think 2010 has support for `for` range loops.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 does not support this type of for: `for (auto& disk : disks)`

Comment: what can i use instead this code with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 [doesn't come with support for Range-based for-loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx). You will have to type out the equivalent code yourself, in this case that would be:

```
for (auto diskIter = disks.begin(); diskIter != disks.end; ++diskIter)
{
    auto disk = *diskIter;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Visual Studio doesn't support that by default. I tried to add the compiler flags, but didn't work. So you can simply use iterators to fix the error.

```
std::vector<PhysicalDisk*> disks;

// Your code

for (std::vector<PhysicalDisk*>::iterator it = disks.begin(); it != disks.end; it++)
{
    PhysicalDisk* disk = *it;
    // Your code
}
```

Or you can avoid that iterator initialization by using auto.

```
for (auto disk  = disks.begin(); it != disks.end; it++)
{
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: There are no compiler flags for different versions of the standard for MSVC, each version has it's own fixed level of compliance (apart from enabling language extensions) but VS 2010 obviously came out before C++11 was finalised.

Comment: @sjdowling : Thanks for the info. However, I have also tried these type of code and didn't work. I think that was the reason for that. Thanks.